# How to reverse order of z-index in a RelativeLayout that lower Item gain lower z-index?

Tags: android, android-relativelayout

As you know in a "RelativeLayout" lower items have higher z-index how can we reverse this order ?

this is my app's screenshot :

[image: overlap]

i created a complex component at runtime that is so difficult for me to changing it's order .i used animation in that and ,as you see, it has overlap with next element and i want to solve this issue with changing order of z-index of my RelativeLayout , is there any solution to do this?

sorry for bad English

thank you so much

Comment: what items you want to place in top write that a the bottom. Just cut and paste to top.

Comment: You need post more code.How you create that complex component?And better with the layout.xml for your content view.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is what you looking for?

[`View.bringToFront()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#bringToFront()), just use it for bad component. In your case it will be green marks. 
 This method brings up the view over other views located in layout.

or if you draw components on the Canvas you should just swap lines of code that respond for drawing each view.

Comment: sorry but this is not my answer , View.bringToFront() will change order of element in it's parent and since i used element index to get it programatically, i cant change my RelativeLayout's order of child elements. but thank you for your answer brother

Comment: @ArshiaJafarzadeh what you giving as element by index?

Comment: my intended purpose from word "Element" are Views like ImageView

Comment: @ArshiaJafarzadeh but... ImageView is a child of View. Why you can not call bring to front on given View by index?

Comment: because i have a relative layout , and call it's children by calling their index of position in that layout (1) , BringToFront() changes the  order of their childrens and destroys everything . BringToFront() is helpful when order of childrens is not matter. thank you brother :) . 1.return (ImageView) this.mContainer.getChildAt(index)

Comment: @ArshiaJafarzadeh seems, I got it. Under `destroy everything` you mean, that your View loosing locations and alignments , that you was set to this View, yes?

Comment: @ArshiaJafarzadeh the problem is `your View loosing locations and alignments` is actually losing LayoutParams. So you need save it before using bringToFront(). And after restore it via `setLayoutParams(yourSavedParams)`.